# How to display images in excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to display images in excel file which is generated out of my c# code. Currently I am generating the xls file using the following code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string imageInitialPath = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Substring(0, Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().LastIndexOf('/'));

sb.Append("<table border=1><tr><td colspan=3 rowspan=5 style=text-align: left;><img src='" + imageInitialPath + "/images/abc.JPG'/></td></tr></table>");
```

Here I am giving the path of an image from some folder. The image is gone from excel when deleted from that folder. Is there a way to keep the image in excel without actually depending on source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The image in the resulting excel file may still be referenced via the link, since the source is html.

I would suggest creating an actual Excel file format using this free library: http://epplus.codeplex.com/